# How to program a trunked System into radioshack pro 651?

Tags: radio-programming

am new to this forum, so tell me if this question is out of place - as it concerns a scanner.

I have an old radioshack pro-651 (same model as pro 106, and whistler 1040) that I am trying to program with the [NJICS TRS](https://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?sid=7021).

I have added the TSYS object as follows, using the frequencies of West Orange Simulcast site.

```
    Type:MOT VHF/UHF
    Frequencies:
            769.19375
            769.45625
            769.66875
            769.96875
            770.44375
            770.66875
            770.91875
            773.34375
            773.79375
            774.31875
            774.54375
            774.78125
```

Everything else is on the default setting.

I added a TGRP object with id: `Wildcard`

However after consistent monitoring, I fail to pick up anything.
Am not sure if I'm leaving out any important fields.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  In my opinion scanner questions are on-topic here, because they are radio technology and people use them to listen to ham radio transmissions, but questions about trunked systems are not, because hams don't use trunking.  So you're in a bit of a gray area (but I'm not a moderator).  Anyway, hello and we're glad you stopped by!

Comment: Oh, and what software did you use to program your scanner?

Comment: thanks @rclocher3 . i tried to use arc500 , it downloads fine from my scanner, but it wont upload to the scanner, so actually did this manually

Comment: @rclocher3 I found several scanner questions, so it's on-topic enough for me; it's not an OT business question. (I couldn't find anything about trunking, but IIRC there was a deleted question about trunked systems. But I think one of those might have been a jamming question.)